Question about perpendicular line segment bisector
Problem: Let $P$ and $Q$ be the projections of the orthocenter $H$ of the acute triangle $ABC$ onto the internal and external angle bisectors of angle $A$, respectively. Prove that $P$, $Q$, and $D$, the midpoint of side $BC$, lie on a straight line.
Solution: Let $AA_1$, $BB_1$, and $CC_1$ be the three altitudes of the triangle, and let $AP$ and $AQ$ represent the internal and external angle bisectors of $\angle BAC$, respectively. Since the internal and external angle bisectors are perpendicular to each other, it follows that $AP \perp AQ$. By construction, $HP \perp AP$ and $HQ \perp AQ$. From this, it follows that $AQHP$ forms a rectangle, in which the diagonals bisect each other and are equal, implying that $AH = PQ$, with $R$ being the midpoint of the diagonals.
In the quadrilateral $AB_1HC_1$, $HB_1A$ and $HC_1A$ are right angles ($90^\circ$), making it a cyclic quadrilateral. The circumcircle of this quadrilateral has $AH$ as its diameter, meaning that $A$, $Q$, $H$, $P$, $B_1$, and $C_1$ lie on the same circle. Thus, $PQ$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of segment $B_1C_1$.
Since $\angle BC_1C = \angle BB_1C = 90^\circ$, the quadrilateral $BC_1B_1C$ is also cyclic, and its circumcircle has $BC$ as its diameter. The center of this circle is $D$, the midpoint of $BC$. It follows that the perpendicular bisector of segment $B_1C_1$ passes through $D$ as well, which implies that $D$, $P$, and $Q$ are collinear.

Question:

I know it seems trivial, but I don't understand why if $A,Q,H,P,B_1$ and $C_1$ lie on the same circle, then $PQ$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of segment $B_1C_1$.

Why, if $D$ is the center of the circle and $BC$ is the diameter, does the perpendicular bisector of segment $B_1C_1$ pass through $D$?




This is the point called the A-Humpty point in olympiad circles :)


Since $\angle B_1AP=\angle C_1AP$, we have that $P$ is the midpoint of minor arc $B_1C_1$. Any line connecting the center of a circle to the midpoint of the arc formed by two points is the perpendicular bisector of the chord formed by those two points.

For any two intersecting circles, the line connecting their centers is the perpendicular bisector of the line connecting their intersection points. So, the perpendicular bisector of $B_1C_1$ must pass through the center of $(BC_1B_1C)$, which is just $D$.



The centres of your two circles must lie on the perpendicular bisector of the chord $B_1C_1$, since $DB_1 = DC_1$ and $RB_1=RC_1$, so $DR$ is the bisector in question. Therefore we need to show $P$ (or $Q$) lies on this line. Using that $AP$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC$, we have
$$ \angle PB_1C_1 = \angle PAC_1 = \angle P_AB_1 = \angle PC_1B_1 $$
so triangle $PB_1C_1$ is isosceles and we win.
